# elasticsearch template doesn't change index ILM

Tags: elasticsearch, ilm

in my elasticsearch, I will receive daily index with format like dstack-prod_dcbs-. I want to add ILM to them, immediately after they are revived. I dont know why ILM are not added to indexs. below you can find my command.(I have already defined "dstack-prod_dcbs-policy" ILM)

```
*PUT _template/dstack-prod_dcbs
{
  "index_patterns": ["dstack-prod_dcbs-*"], 
  "settings": {
    "index.lifecycle.name": "dstack-prod_dcbs-policy"
}
}*
```

but when I run

**GET dstack-prod_dcbs*/_ilm/explain**

below result returns

```
*{
  "indices" : {
    "dstack-prod_dcbs-20200821" : {
      "index" : "dstack-prod_dcbs-20200821",
      "managed" : false
    },
    "dstack-prod_dcbs-2020-09-22" : {
      "index" : "dstack-prod_dcbs-2020-09-22",
      "managed" : false
    }
  }
}*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ILM is an alternative to using daily indices where indices are rolled over when a condition is met in the policy (not when it becomes a new day)

For ILM you need to define a rollover alias for the template

```
PUT _template/dstack-prod_dcbs
{
  "index_patterns": ["dstack-prod_dcbs-*"], 
  "settings": {
    "index.lifecycle.name": "dstack-prod_dcbs-policy",
    "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "dstack-prod_dcbs"
  } 
}
```

Then you need to create the first index manually and assign it as the write index for the alias

```
PUT dstack-prod_dcbs-000001
{
   "aliases": {
        "dstack-prod_dcbs":{
            "is_write_index": true 
        }
    }
}
```

After that everything will be handled automatically and a new index will be created on rollover which will be then assigned as the write index for the alias

Comment: Thanks for your response. when I do for new index like test (insted of dstack-prod_dcbs) everything is ok, but when I use them dor dstack-prod_dcbs, I got   "indices" : {
    "dstack-prod_dcbs-20200821" : {
      "index" : "dstack-prod_dcbs-20200821",
      "managed" : false
    },   . I removed all indexes with dstack-prod_dcbs pattern

Comment: Yes you need to create the template before you create the indices so you need to delete the dstack-prod_dcbs indices and create them after you create the template so that the policy can get assigned to them

Comment: I removed elasticsearch volumes, and its work correctly now. I think sometimes elastic doesn't shows indexs but actually they are exist.